# GE model numbers

Tags: dryer

I'm trying to order some drum slides, Upper Drum support, felt drum seal and timer for a 15-20 year old GE electric cloths dryer. Contacting GE as well as the owners manual and several sites on the web say the SN/ model number should be on the front case with the door open. There is no tag in this area. I have compared the pictures of the control panel in owners manual with my dryer and figured out it is a DVLR223. Only problem is this is only the base model number and I need the whole number to buy parts. Is there any way to tell what those letters after the base number mean?

Comment: It may be the distributor. I'm pretty sure different stores will sometimes sell the same product with unique product numbers to avoid price matching their competitors.

Answer (score 1):

The letters at the very end generally refer to the style or color of the appliance. W = White, B = Black, Q = "Bisque" (almond, off-white), S = Stainless etc. For an internal part it probably won't matter since you won't have to consider color.